# StackWalk64() returns a single frame

Tags: debugging, winapi, dbghelp

When trying to obtain the call stack of a thread of some process, I always get a single same frame, although it is for sure has more (at least 5 frames).

StackWalk64() always succeeds on the first call - return a frame with:

```
AddrPC.Offset = 18446744072850558156
```

But, immediately on the second call it fails with error id 998-ERROR_NOACCESS (it might be that this error is not because of this call, as MSDN says).

Moreover, trying to resolve this address into its symbol name with SymFromAddr() fails with error 126-ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND (after successful SymInitialize(m_processHandler,NULL,TRUE) call).

Here is the code:

```
#ifdef _M_IX86
  //
  // Disable global optimization and ignore /GS waning caused by
  // inline assembly.
  //
  #pragma optimize( "g", off )
  #pragma warning( push )
  #pragma warning( disable : 4748 )
#endif

bool EchoProfiler::getThreadStackTrace(__in HANDLE h_thread, __out vector<DWORD64> &framesVec)
{
CONTEXT threadContext;
if (GetThreadContext(h_thread, &threadContext) == 0)
{
    cout << "Error: GetThreadContext() failed with error ID " << GetLastError() << endl;
    return false;
}

//initialize stack frame
DWORD MachineType;
STACKFRAME64 StackFrame;
ZeroMemory( &StackFrame, sizeof( STACKFRAME64 ) );

MachineType                 = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;
StackFrame.AddrPC.Offset    = threadContext.Eip;
StackFrame.AddrPC.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
StackFrame.AddrFrame.Offset = threadContext.Ebp;
StackFrame.AddrFrame.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
StackFrame.AddrStack.Offset = threadContext.Esp;
StackFrame.AddrStack.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;

PVOID contextRec = (MachineType == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386) ? NULL : &threadContext;
int i=0;
// enumerate all the frames in the stack
for (i=1 ; ; i++)
{
    if (StackWalk64( MachineType, targetProcessHandler, h_thread, &StackFrame,
        contextRec, NULL, SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL ) == false)
    {
        // in case it failed or we have finished walking the stack.
        cout << "Error: StackWalk64() failed with error ID " << GetLastError() << endl;
        i--;
        break;
        // return false;
    }

    if ( StackFrame.AddrPC.Offset != 0 )
    {
        // Valid frame.
        cout << "Frame #" << i << " address - " << StackFrame.AddrPC.Offset << endl;
        framesVec.push_back(StackFrame.AddrPC.Offset);
    }
    else
    {
        // Base reached.
        break;
    }
}

//cout << "StackWalk64 found " << i << " stack frames:" << endl;
//i = 1;
//for (FramesConstItr itr=framesVec.begin() ; itr != framesVec.end() ; itr++ , i++)
//  cout << i << " - " << *itr << endl;

return true;
}

#ifdef _M_IX86
  #pragma warning( pop )
  #pragma optimize( "g", on )
#endif
```

what could it be?

Comment: What is targetProcessHandler and how is it initialized?

Comment: Initialized using `HANDLE targetProcessHandler = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,pId)`

Comment: How did you get StackWalk64 to SetLastError? I'm having some issues as well but GetLastError() returns 0 even after StackWalk64 returns false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

I missed the part  said that the context structure must be initialize properly.
Adding the following solved my problem:

```
memset(&threadContext, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));
threadContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you disable optimization here, Hagay ? It looks like you are absolutely right doing that, but why, is it required ? I get incorrect stack in case I don't disable optimization in my app. I see fewer function addresses in the output of my stack printer application. Do you have any idea what can be the cause ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into this issue in the future, I also suffered from it in our own local codebase when getting stack information from a different process to the current one. The cause was that we were missing PROCESS_VM_READ when getting a handle on the process using OpenProcess().

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the StackWalker project on github.
It has a BSD-2 license if you wish to use it directly.
It is great working sample code if you prefer to make your own.

[https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker](https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker/)